# Meta SO link in main menu is http when viewing over https

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, ssl

The Meta Stack Overflow link on the main menu (the one that branches off from the main site link under "CURRENT COMMUNITY") shows up as an http link, even when using https on the main site, and all other links in the menu are https.

The seems to be the case on other SE sites too.

Comment: Aside from not yet supporting HTTPS fully, this was completely intentional before because CloudFlare did not allow the use of invalid certificates on secure connections, thus sending users to the secure Meta site from almost every other site on the network would break the user experience - they'd just land on an error page, which isn't ideal. It was far better to send them to the non-secure site instead. This will eventually be fixed when we fully support HTTPS.